# Migrating existing web application to a silverlight based application

Tags: silverlight

I have a web application developed in .net 2.0 and VS 2005. I want to make use of features provided by Silverlight. Is it possible for me to use Silverlight in the existing application itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, there is no need to migrate web application as Silverlight app. Silverlight is very specific technology provided by Microsoft for Rich Internet Web Application development for .NET (ASP.NET) Framework.

Silverlight is the technology which is used for Rich Internet (client-side) application on top of ASP.NET (server-side) application like Flash. If you want to add Silverlight contols or framwork into your existing web (ASP.NET) application, you can add it for any version of ASP .NET application, no need to migrate into silverlight version.

Current version ASP.NET is ASP.NET 4, currespoding Silverlight version is Silverlight 4.